# Using 'self' in for loop and conditional statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am learning linkedlists in python. In this website, and in one of the methods,

```
    def add_last(self, node):
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = node
        return
    for current_node in self:
        pass
    current_node.next = node
```

What does the line `for current_node in self:` mean? How could one iterate through `self`? What does it mean to iterate through `self`?

Below is the entire code for the implementation of a linkedlist in python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
  
    def __init__(self, nodes=None):
        self.head = None
        if nodes is not None:
            node = Node(data=nodes.pop(0))
            self.head = node
        for elem in nodes:
            node.next = Node(data=elem)
            node = node.next
    
    def __repr__(self):
        node = self.head
        nodes = []
        while node is not None:
            nodes.append(node.data)
            node = node.next
        nodes.append("None")
        return " -> ".join(nodes)
```

Comment: "for current_node in self" can't work with the shown implementation. "LinkedList" would have to provide a properly implemented `__iter__` method to become an iterable and support this "for...".

Comment: @MichaelButscher there is an __iter__ method
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    while node is not None:
        yield node
        node = node.next

Comment: So the "entire code" isn't the entire code?

Answer (score 1):

In python, we can use several different types/classes in for loops (i.e. lists, strings, etc). The python interpreter will accept any object that is an **iterable** when building a for loop. For a object to be an **iterable**, its class must implement the `__iter__` method. As long as the class implements this method, python doesn't care if you refer to the object using `self` or a standard variable.

Here is an example from the wiki page of an iterable object. Note that there is another layer to this with the `__next__` method. A class with `__next__` defined is called an **iterator**. The **iterator** provides the actual logic for producing a sequence of elements for the for loop. An **iterable** must return an **iterator** object with `__iter__` For more complex types, the **iterator** may need to be a separate class from the **iterable**, but in simple cases (like the following example) they can be the same class.

```py
    import random
    
    class RandomIterable:
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def __next__(self):
            if random.choice(["go", "go", "stop"]) == "stop":
                raise StopIteration  # signals "the end"
            return 1
```

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator

Answer (score 1):

In comments you explain that the `LinkedList` class has this method:

```
def __iter__(self): 
    node = self.head
    while node is not None:
        yield node
        node = node.next
```

This makes it possible to iterate an instance of `LinkedList` with a `for..in` loop. In fact the following piece of code in `add_last`:

```
    for current_node in self:
        pass
```

Can be written in more verbose manner like this:

```
    it = iter(self)
    try:
        while True:
            current_node = next(it)
    except:
        pass
```

So `add_node` could have been written like this:

```
def add_last(self, node):
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = node
        return
    it = iter(self)
    try:
        while True:
            current_node = next(it)
    except:
        current_node.next = node
```

`it` represents the iterator that the `for` loop implicitly creates, but with this code it is easier to follow what is happening.

Let's say you have two nodes in your list with values 1 and 2, then the execution sequence of the more verbose `add_node` is as follows:

| `add_last` | `__iter__` |
| --- | --- |
| `self.head is not None` |  |
| `it = iter(self)` |  |
| `next(it)` |  |
|  | `node = self.head` |
|  | `node is not None` |
|  | `yield node` (with value 1) |
| `current_node =` (node with value 1) |  |
| `next(it)` |  |
|  | `node = node.next` |
|  | `node is not None` |
|  | `yield node` (with value 2) |
| `current_node =` (node with value 2) |  |
| `next(it)` |  |
|  | `node = node.next` |
|  | `node is None` (!) |
|  | `raise StopIteration()` (implicit) |
| `except:` |  |
| `current_node.next = node` |  |

Effectively, the last value of `current_node` is the last node in the list, and assigning the new node to its `next` attribute is exactly what you want to happen to extend the list with that node.

### Other comments

Not your question, but there are some issues in your code:

- The second `__init__` definition in `LinkedList` overwrites the first. There is no such concept of overloading in Python. But also you don't need the first definition in this case, as the second version has a default value for its second parameter.
- The indentation of the `for` loop in that `__init__` method is wrong. It should be inside the `if` block.
- Calling `.pop(0)` is not nice for the caller of the constructor: it mutates the given list, and this might be an undesired side-effect for the caller.
- The `__repr__` method on `ListNode` assumes that the values received from `Node`'s `__repr__` method are strings, as otherwise the `join` will fail. If ever you want to use nodes for storing integers (for example), this method will fail. To avoid that, cast `self.data` to string in the `Node`'s `__repr__` method.